# Windows 7 Volume Mixer forgets Mute state

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, audio

Lately, my mute setting for Chrome is reset every time I load a page.

Does anyone have a clue as to what is causing that? Chrome and Windows are updated to the latest state.

I must mention that my Windows installation is fresh. I reinstalled this week but it started before and a fresh install didn't do anything (i was kinda hoping to be honest...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is because each tab is actually a different process, but the mute-state is per-process. Consequently when you mute Chrome, you're actually only muting one tab at a time.

Comment: Chrome has always had each tab as a separate processs and this is definitely a new issue (as of the last few days), usually (and with other applications) Windows 7 remembers the settings between closing/opening the application.

Comment: The difference here is that sound used to be brokered to the parent process and so muting the tab muted the whole browser. Sound is now played directly from the tab, so muting the tab doesn't mute any of the other tabs in the window

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround - although the mute state isn't remembered, the volume is remembered between processes, so you can set the volume of that process to 0 to mute it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Chrome Toolbox (which you can find at the Chrome Web Store) to be able to mute Chrome completely, among other things.

Don't forget you installed it though, because you might end up muting Youtube et al and not knowing why it's happening.